# Installing a Python library wheel in an Azure Machine Learning Compute Cluster

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service

I am working on an Azure Machine Learning Studio pipeline via the Designer. I need to install a Python library wheel (a third-party tool) in the same compute, so that I can import it into the designer. I usually install packages to compute instances via the terminal, but the Azure Machine Learning Studio designer uses a compute cluster, not a compute instance.

Is there any way to access the terminal so that I can install the wheel in the compute cluster and have access to the library via the designer? Thanks!

Comment: can you share the terminal script that you normally use to install?

Comment: I usually use pip through the terminal, using something similar to python -m wheel install wheel_file.whl.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an easy path for this. Your options are either, switch to a code-first pipeline definition approach, or try your darndest to extend the Designer UI to meet your needs.

### Define pipelines with v2 CLI or Python SDK

It looks like you're already outside of I get the impression that you know Python quite well, you should really check out the [v2 CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure/azureml-examples/azure-machine-learning-20-cli-preview-examples/) or the [Python SDK for Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/concept-ml-pipelines). I'd recommend maybe starting with the v2 CLI as it will be the way to define AML jobs in the future.

Both require some initial learning, but will give you all the flexibility that isn't currently available in the UI.

### custom Docker image

The "Execute Python Script" module allows use a custom python Docker image. I *think* this works? I just tried it but not with a custom .whl file, and it looked like it worked

[image: module Run settings]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you give me some details on how you got the Docker image ready with the wheel file?

Comment: If you could give me details for the v2 CLI that would work as well; either one is fine. Yes, I am quite familiar with Python. Thanks again!